# Restart a Running Sum after Static Threshold

Tags: postgresql, aws, redshift

I've been stuck trying to solve the following problem for some time: I essentially want to restart the rolling sum if the rolling sum exceeds 3600, else continue summing. I've sort of have it working by creating a new sum that goes off a `switch` group.

```
select id, group, value, rolling_sum
sum(value) over (partition by id, group, switch) as rolling_sum_final
from
(
select id, group, value, rolling_sum
(rolling_sum*1.0/3600*1.0) as switch
from tbl
)
```

```
| id  | group | value | rolling sum | switch | rolling_sum_final |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ----------- | ------ | ----------------- |
| 100 | 12    | 835   | 835         | 0      | 835               |
| 100 | 12    | 2769  | 3604        | 1      | 2769              |
| 100 | 12    | 3597  | 7201        | 2      | 3597              |
| 100 | 12    | 1360  | 8561        | 2      | 4957              |
| 100 | 12    | 2232  | 10793       | 3      | 2232              |
```

The problem with the current approach is values like `1360` should restart but doesn't because it's technically still part of the same `switch` scale multiple. Is there a better way to do this, my goal is the following. Don't need specific solutions, just general pseudo-code will do, thanks.

```
| id  | group | value | rolling sum | switch | rolling_sum_final |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ----------- | ------ | ----------------- |
| 100 | 12    | 835   | 835         | 0      | 835               |
| 100 | 12    | 2769  | 3604        | 1      | 2769              |
| 100 | 12    | 3597  | 7201        | 2      | 3597              |
| 100 | 12    | 1360  | 8561        | 3      | 1360              |
| 100 | 12    | 2232  | 10793       | 3      | 3592              |
```

Here is a simplified [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314149/how-to-reset-cumulative-sum-when-reached-to-threshold) of what I'm trying to do recursively using a smaller threshold of 300, but even this also doesn't seem to work.

```
drop table if exists test;
create temp table test (pk int,amount int);

insert into test values (1,1000);
insert into test values (2,20);
insert into test values (3,50);
insert into test values (4,100);
insert into test values (5,120);
insert into test values (6,50);
insert into test values (7,200);
insert into test values (8,100);
insert into test values (9,1000);
insert into test values (10,200);

create temp table test_2 as 
select *,sum(amount) over (order by seq_num asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_amount
from (select *, row_number() over (order by pk ) as seq_num from test)

with recursive cte (seq_num, pk, amount, running_amount) as 
(
    select seq_num, pk, amount, running_amount
    from test_2
    where seq_num = 1
    
    union all 
    
    select t.seq_num, t.pk, t.amount
            ,(case when t.running_amount > 300 then t.amount
                   else t.running_amount end)
              end as running_amount
      from cte 
        join test_2 as t
           on t.seq_num = cte.seq_num + 1
)
select * from cte;
```

Comment: I guess I'm too dump, but I don't understand the algorithm. It seems that you don't want `(sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, group ORDER BY whatever)) % 3600 AS rolling sum, (sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, group ORDER BY whatever)) / 3600 AS switch`. Can you describe the rules to calculate `rolling_sum` and `switch` in more detail?

Comment: rules is that the when the rolling sum exceeds 3600 (ex. 835+2769 = 3604) > 3600, then I want the rolling sum to restart (so 835,  then 2769 instead of 3604, so on and so forth). The `switch` column is just a group of values that don't require restarting (ex. 1360 + 2232 = 3592).

Comment: How exactly do you get from 3604 to 2769?

Comment: 3604 -> 2769 is essentially akin to something like `sum(value) over (partition by id, group, switch order by whatever rows between unbounded preceding and current row)`. Essentially narrowing the rolling sum to a new window range of values that don't exceed the threshold. Windows that do (ex. `switch = [0,1,2]`) keep the same rolling sum value since there is only row inside it.

Comment: I mean, what exact addition or subtraction or other arithmetic operation results in 2769? If I see that, perhaps I can understand your algorithm.

Comment: I can't figure that out either... that's what I'm having trouble with. Only way so far I've been able to get closer to the solution is by recursively checking if the running sum exceeds the threshold but this is slow and would prefer the SQL to be pure.

Comment: So you don't know yourself what the logic behind all that is. Good luck with finding someone who can guess. Perhaps you should ask the people who gave you this assignment.